# XNA-WP7: making small earth and continent plate

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, geometry

What I want to make is the Earth.
Like a Google Map(that zoom out one), I want to display the earth sphere in center.

Then, I want to divide the surface of earth with random continent plate.

My main question is, how can i make the earth and continent plate like nintendo's Animal Crossing?

I have just finish display the Sphere what made by 3DMax. (.fbx file)

Comment: Upvoted for the spirit of [Slartibartfast](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/hitchhikers/guide/slartibartfast.shtml)!

Comment: Would you like to physically split up the sphere into sections, or just draw textured continent dividers on top of the sphere?